# При определенном классе, меняется стиль другого блока

Tags: javascript, css

При клике на меню пункт получает класс `.active` и переходит на страницу где есть слева каталог. Нужно что бы при `.cat-parent:nth-child(1).active` каталог с классом `.list-group` менял `background`, к примеру на фиолетовый, а если `.cat-parent:nth-child(2).active`, то на голубой. Возможно ли такое сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<ul class="product-categories">
    <li class="cat-item  active"><a href="#">Продукты</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Еда со смыслом</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Бытовая химия</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Ионизаторы Aquaspectr</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Бад</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Идеи</a></li>
</ul>
```

Каталог

```
<div class='list-group'>
    <a href='#section10' class='list-group-item' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#subsection10' >
        TUPPERWARE
    </a>
    <div id='subsection10' class="collapse">
        <a href='#' class='list-group-item small'>Сварочное оборудование</a>
        <a href='#' class='list-group-item small'>Электрододержатели, зажимы</a>
        <a href='#' class='list-group-item small'>Электроды</a>
    </div>
    <a href='#section14' class='list-group-item' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#subsection14' >
        Сервировка
    </a>
    <div id='subsection14' class="collapse">
        <a href='#' class='list-group-item small'>Сварочное оборудование</a>
        <a href='#' class='list-group-item small'>Горелки для полуавтоматов</a>
        <a href='#' class='list-group-item small'>Комплектующие к горелкам</a>
        <a href='#' class='list-group-item small'>Проволока</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможно всё! Код то где?

Comment: @АлексейДрижаков В голове перебирал вариант в проверкой класса на странице через hasClass, но получиться тогда большой код в js

Comment: Я пока идею подам. В функции события создаёте массив типа colorArray =  [ 'blue', 'violet', '#4fa322', '#FFFF00', 'red', 'grey' ] Проверяете в детях cat-parent порядковый номер <li>с классом '.active'.  Затем извлекаете этот номер (к примеру у Вас получился "3") и присваиваете list-group.style.background = colorArray[извлечённый номер (в Вашем случае "3") ];

Comment: @АлексейДрижаков Не могли ли бы вы помочь составить код пожалуйста, я не знаю как создать такую проверку и нагуглить не могу

Comment: Я пока тоже думаю. Хотелось бы помочь, пробую, об успехах сообщу.

Comment: @АлексейДрижаков огромное Вам спасибо, Вы мне очень помогли

Comment: Приятно быть полезным :-))

Comment: @АлексейДрижаков Есть проблема, в том что при переходе на страницу, пропадает класс active

Comment: Cкорее всего вы переходите на другую страницу. Тогда, может Вам понадобится просто вручную прописать класс active на каждой странице в html для выбранного (активного) <li>. Тогда не надо будет добавлять класс через js. Может дело и не в этом, но тогда структуру сайта надо видеть. Тогда вопрос не совсем для этого ресурса

Comment: @АлексейДрижаков да, происходит переход и он сбрасывает стиль

Comment: Если страниц немного, то можно просто прописать в  каждой стиль для каталога <div class="list-group" ="background: необходимый цвет"> Если к каждой странице подключён Ваш js, можно попробовать через $( document ).ready присвоить стиль для текущего каталога.

Comment: @АлексейДрижаков Да сработало, еще раз огромное Вам спасибо, теперь при переходе на страницу ничего не сбрасывается. Вы меня очень выручили, извините, что некорректно изначально разъяснил свою мысль.

Comment: На всякий случай, здесь реально можно найти ответ, но надо правильно формулировать вопрос. сформировать именно тот участок кода, где проблема и выдать на обозрение. Правда, когда формулируешь вопрос таким образом, то и сам ответ уже видишь :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я изменил функцию на document.ready. Вам тогда надо прописать вручную класс active для пунктов, на странице которого находится сайт. Я об этом в комментарии написал. Или смотреть какая функция присваивает класс .active по клику. Тогда можно в эту функцию вставить массив и присвоение по индексу как в первом ответе. Посмотрите на код, там несложно. Если не получится, боюсь не смогу помочь, потому что приходится действовать в режиме догадок :-). Поймите, если не видно всего кода, то и непонятно как реализовывать))).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.cat-item').each(function() {
    var colorArray = ['blue', 'violet', 'yellow', 'red', 'green', 'grey'];
    var listGroup = document.getElementById('list-group1');
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        listGroup.style.background = (colorArray[$(this).index()]);
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Получилось с помощью jquery. Немного не то, что Вы просили, здесь цветов столько сколько кнопок в меню, а не с помощью nth:child. Как вариант, можете просто поочерёдно поставить те цвета, которые нужны. Вроде получилось!

```js
var colorArray = ['blue', 'violet', 'yellow', 'red', 'green', 'grey'];
var listGroup = document.getElementById('list-group1');

$('.cat-item').click(function(event) {
    $('.cat-item').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
   
    listGroup.style.background = (colorArray[$(this).index()]);
});
```

```css
#list-group1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<ul class="product-categories" id="procat">
            <li class="cat-item ">
                <a href="#">
                    Продукты
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item">
                <a href="#">
                    Еда со смыслом
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item active">
                <a href="#">
                    Бытовая химия
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item">
                <a href="#">
                    Ионизаторы Aquaspectr
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item">
                <a href="#">
                    Бад
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item">
                <a href="#">
                    Идеи
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="list-group" id="list-group1">
            <a class="list-group-item" data-target="#subsection10" data-toggle="collapse" href="#section10">
                TUPPERWARE
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="subsection10">
                <a class="list-group-item small" href="#">
                    Сварочное оборудование
                </a>
                <a class="list-group-item small" href="#">
                    Электрододержатели, зажимы
                </a>
                <a class="list-group-item small" href="#">
                    Электроды
                </a>
            </div>
            <a class="list-group-item" data-target="#subsection14" data-toggle="collapse" href="#section14">
                Сервировка
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="subsection14">
                <a class="list-group-item small" href="#">
                    Сварочное оборудование
                </a>
                <a class="list-group-item small" href="#">
                    Горелки для полуавтоматов
                </a>
                <a class="list-group-item small" href="#">
                    Комплектующие к горелкам
                </a>
                <a class="list-group-item small" href="#">
                    Проволока
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Да, и ещё один момент, к блоку каталога я обратился, добавив идентификатор. В общем идея, надеюсь понятна, а там дерзайте!!!